# Keycloak logout request does not log out user

Tags: session, cookies, authentication, logout, keycloak

I am currently working on a small project using keycloak 2.5.0
I've already set up the user login and i'm now trying to implement a page wide **logout** button.

As the [documentation](https://keycloak.gitbooks.io/securing-client-applications-guide/content/topics/oidc/java/logout.html) states, is simply called the route
*http: //my-auth-server/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/logout?redirect_uri=http: //application-root.com/*
For the sake of simplicity i used an anchor tag to make this **GET** Request.

If i take a look into the Network tab of the firefox developer tools everything seems to be working fine. I am getting back a **302** status code for the redirection request. And after that, the application successfully requests the *http: //application-root.com/* with a status code of **200** and redirects me to this page.

But when i want to **request the locked content** again (the one secured by keycloak) its **still accessible**.

But whenever i manually delete the **JSESSIONID** and **KEYCLOAK_ADAPTER_STATE** cookie after the redirection, everything works fine and i'm being logged out correctly. Sadly i **can't delete those cookies** programmaticly because they are HttpOnly

What is the expected behaviour of this request ?

Am i missing something ?

Has anyone experienced anything similar ?

Thanks for any help

Comment: I had a similar issue because I was not passing the params `refresh_token` and `client_id` as data to que logout request. The logout endpoint always returns 200 OK even if not OK. Can you try it and see what happens? Anyway, I'm missing some info here. Are you using Spring adapter? What is your config?

Comment: any answer for this ?

Comment: @Ruben: I can't see that `refresh_token` and `client_id` are valid params according to the [docs](https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/11.0/javadocs/org/keycloak/protocol/oidc/endpoints/LogoutEndpoint.html)... Do have more info on what you did?

Comment: @PeterV.Mørch This was 3 years ago, most probably things has changed and my response not longer make sense. I was referring to include the refresh_token and client_id in the HTTP body request to logout. This fields values are provided in the login response.

Answer (score 4):

I implemented logout using Keycloak 4.8.3 version. Mandatory parameter is id token (id_token_hint). Optional parameter is redirect url (post_logout_redirect_uri).
Example:

*http: //my-auth-server/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/logout?id_token_hint=eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCIgOiAiSldUIiwia2lkIiA6ICJEY0gyNnl0OFV0OEJQTGxoR&post_logout_redirect_uri=http:%2F%2Fapplication-root.com%2F*

Comment: This helped point me in the right direction. It's worth mentioning that this is a GET request that works as a quick back-channel logout strategy. The return code is clean (200 OK), so you can depend on that for error checking in your code.

Comment: @BlakeNeal: You say "This helped point me in the right direction". Do you any of you remember what that right direction was? I tried sending the `id_token_hint` and `post_logout_redirect_uri` with the same results.

Comment: @andrija: That id_token_hint looks very short... It is just the beginning of the id_token that you manually cut short so it looked nice here, right? Or was this the literal GET you sent?

Comment: Yes, Peter. Real id token is much longer.