# Keycloak cookies not cleared after logout (kc-access, kc-access-1)

Tags: keycloak, openid, keycloak-gatekeeper

In my web application I have a logout mechanism that redirects to the Keycloak logout page `/auth/realms/account-1/protocol/openid-connect/logout`, which looks like this:

[image]

Clicking the Logout button, a request is being sent to:

```
POST /auth/realms/account-1/protocol/openid-connect/logout/logout-confirm?client_id=account&tab_id=hvJMKC-Rbbc
```

And the response headers are clearing most of the cookies using the Expire flag:

```
HTTP/2 200 
content-language: en
content-security-policy: frame-src 'self'; frame-ancestors 'self'; object-src 'none';
content-type: text/html;charset=utf-8
referrer-policy: no-referrer
set-cookie: KEYCLOAK_IDENTITY=; Version=1; Comment=Expiring cookie; Expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:10 GMT; Max-Age=0; Path=/auth/realms/account-1/; HttpOnly
set-cookie: KEYCLOAK_IDENTITY_LEGACY=; Version=1; Comment=Expiring cookie; Expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:10 GMT; Max-Age=0; Path=/auth/realms/account-1/; HttpOnly
set-cookie: KEYCLOAK_SESSION=; Version=1; Comment=Expiring cookie; Expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:10 GMT; Max-Age=0; Path=/auth/realms/account-1/
set-cookie: KEYCLOAK_SESSION_LEGACY=; Version=1; Comment=Expiring cookie; Expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:10 GMT; Max-Age=0; Path=/auth/realms/account-1/
set-cookie: KEYCLOAK_IDENTITY=; Version=1; Comment=Expiring cookie; Expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:10 GMT; Max-Age=0; Path=/auth/realms/account-1; HttpOnly
set-cookie: KEYCLOAK_IDENTITY_LEGACY=; Version=1; Comment=Expiring cookie; Expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:10 GMT; Max-Age=0; Path=/auth/realms/account-1; HttpOnly
set-cookie: KEYCLOAK_SESSION=; Version=1; Comment=Expiring cookie; Expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:10 GMT; Max-Age=0; Path=/auth/realms/account-1
set-cookie: KEYCLOAK_SESSION_LEGACY=; Version=1; Comment=Expiring cookie; Expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:10 GMT; Max-Age=0; Path=/auth/realms/account-1
set-cookie: KEYCLOAK_REMEMBER_ME=; Version=1; Comment=Expiring cookie; Expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:10 GMT; Max-Age=0; Path=/auth/realms/account-1/; HttpOnly
strict-transport-security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
x-content-type-options: nosniff
x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
x-robots-tag: none
x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
content-length: 1745
date: Wed, 06 Dec 2023 10:20:13 GMT
X-Firefox-Spdy: h2
```

But some headers like kc-access and kc-access-1 remain and those headers are basically just a JWT that can easily be decoded to gain personal user information like given_name, family_name and email.

What am I doing wrong? Why is Keycloak not removing those? Is it possible to get Keycloak to perform a complete and clean logout?

---

In other questions like [Keycloak logout request does not log out user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42295548/keycloak-logout-request-does-not-log-out-user)

people are suggesting to use query parameters `id_token_hint` and `post_logout_redirect_uri`. I don't like this idea though. Essentially, if I wanted to use these parameters, I would have to make the logout button run dynamic code instead of having a JS-independent link that just always works. One bug in my application could mean the logout button stops working.

One alternative that people are suggesting is using `client_id` along with `post_logout_redirect_uri`, but I have tried that and it still doesn't get rid of cookies like kc-access.

I also couldn't find any information on why some cookies are kept in these [docs](https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/21.1.1/javadocs/org/keycloak/protocol/oidc/endpoints/LogoutEndpoint.html#logout(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String)). It just mentions that it works according to spec, which I guess means the OpenID Specifications. But I couldn't find anything about kc-access in the spec.

Comment: Which tech stack you are using and can you provide a little bit of code that you wrote to invoke logout functionality?

Comment: I don't see how this is relevant. I'm running Keycloak in k8s. Keycloak's logout page is invoked by clicking a Link. Imagine `<a href="/auth/realms/account-1/protocol/openid-connect/logout">Logout</a>` styled like a button via CSS. The logout page behind the link can be seen on the screenshot and is something provided by Keycloak. I only know that it's firing the described POST request because I've monitored the network traffic.